# Was wird mit einem CAPSGESCHRIEBENEN Wort gemeint?

Tags: meaning

Ich weiß nicht ob, es zu Thematik des Portals passt, gehört bestimmt aber zu der kulturellen Besonderheiten.

Was meinen Deutsche, wenn sie ein Wort KOMPLETT mit großen Buchstaben schreiben?

Ist das eine Form von Betonung? Weil in meiner Muttersprache das ist sowas in der Art wie Schreien und kann nicht höfflich empfunden werden.

Comment: Was ist Schreien denn, wenn nicht Betonung? Ein komplett in Versalien geschriebenes Wort ist im Allgemeinen nur hervorgehoben, nichts weiter. Dies ist akzeptabel, wenn *kursiv* oder **fett** gerade nicht zur Verfügung stehen.

Comment: Ja und ja: Ist eine Hervorhebung und kommt unangenehm rüber.

Comment: @Chieron, Schreien = Betonung, Betonung ≠ Schreien.

Comment: @Deni die Interpretation als Schreien is neuer als die einfache Betonung. Ich habe aber nie gesagt, dass jede Betonung als Schreien interpretiert werden kann (Versalsatz erscheint aber tendenziell etwas aggressiver, weshalb Fettdruck und Kursivschrift vorzuziehen sind).

Answer (score 1):

Ich bin zwar kein Deutscher sondern ein Österreicher, aber da ich vermute, dass deine Frage eigentlich gar nicht an Deutsche, sondern vielmehr an Deutschsprachige gerichtet ist, erlaube ich mir trotzdem zu antworten. (Nicht alle Deutschen sprechen Deutsch, und nicht alle Deutschsprachigen sind Deutsche)

Erstmal: Es heißt nicht Capsschrift. »Caps« ist kein deutsches Wort, aber das ist zugegebenermaßen kein echtes Kriterium. Ausschlaggebend ist, dass »Caps« in einem deutschsprachigen Kontext eher selten verwendet wird, weil es dafür andere Wörter gibt.

Folgende Begriffe für vollständig in Großbuchstaben geschriebenen Text sind gängig und korrekt:

- Versalschrift
- Majuskelschrift
- Kapitalschrift

Diese Begriffe bezeichnen hingegen etwas anderes:

- Großschrift
  Nur der erste Buchstabe eines Wortes wird mit einem Großbuchstaben geschrieben, alle übrigen mit Kleinbuchstaben.
- Kapitälchenschrift
  Streng genommen ist auch das eine Versalschrift, aber die verwendeten Großbuchstaben haben nur die Schrifthöhe von Kleinbuchstaben. Somit platzen Wörter, die nicht mit Majuskeln, sondern mit Kapitälchen geschrieben sind, nicht so aus dem Schriftbild wie Versalschrift.

Jetzt aber zu deiner Frage:

Eine VERSALSCHRIFT ist eine von mehren verschiedenen Möglichkeiten, Textabschnitte hervorzuheben. Andere Möglichkeiten sind der **Fettdruck**, die *Kursivschrift*, g e s p e r r t e  S c h r i f t und unterstrichene Schrift (letzteres kann ich hier leider nicht darstellen).

Und da jede Hervorhebung in der Aussprache einer Betonung entspricht, ist auch die Versalschrift eine Möglichkeit, eine Betonung auszudrücken. Auf manchen Websites (z.B. Facebook) ist für gewöhnliche Nutzer die Versalschrift neben der gesperrten Schrift, die aber für problematische Zeilenumbrüche und schwer erkennbare Wortgrenzen sorgt, sogar die einzige.

Möchte man in einem geschriebenen Text zum Ausdruck bringen, dass man Teile davon in der gesprochenen Form eigentlich schreien möchte, muss man eine der genannten Auszeichnungsformen verwenden, und gemäß allgemeiner Übereinkunft gilt für diesen Fall die Versalschrift als das Mittel der ersten Wahl.

Insofern darf man sich nicht wundern, wenn Texte, die in Versalschrift verfasst sind, vom Leser als unhöfliches Geschrei interpretiert werden. Daher empfiehlt es sich ganz allgemein, auf Versalschrift zu verzichten, und eine andere Form der Hervorhebung zu verwenden, wenn man etwas zwar hervorheben möchte, aber nicht will, dass andere das als Geschrei verstehen.

Dort, wo aber die Versalschrift die einzige Möglichkeit ist eine Hervorhebung zu machen, sind die Leser gefordert, nicht jedes Wort, das durchgehend in Großbuchstaben geschrieben ist, gleich als Geschrei zu interpretieren. Schließlich steht dem Autor kein anderes Mittel der Hervorhebung zur Verfügung.

Comment: du hättest auch meine Frage ungehindert korrigieren können, damit wäre deine Antwort um eine Hälfte kürzer und lakonischer gewesen.

Comment: @Deni: Ich hatte noch nie Lust kurze lakonische Antworten zu schreiben. Hier sind alle meine Antworten: http://german.stackexchange.com/users/1487/hubert-schölnast?tab=answers Darunter wirst du kaum kurze Antworten finden. Und wenn ich bemerke, dass jemand etwas falsch macht, dann halte ich es für besser zu erklären wie es richtig ist, und warum es richtig ist, als einfach den Fehler zu löschen und durch die richtige Version zu ersetzen. Vom Ausbessern ohne Erklärung lernt man kaum etwas. Eine Erklärung kann helfen, das man in Zukunft diesen Fehler nicht mehr macht.